# Change Tone/Pitch for file audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

In FFMPEG, Can I change tone of audio? If i can, What is the code used? I want change tone/Pitch Random in my audio.mp3? Help me, thank so much!

E.G.: I have a audio.mp3, I want change Pitch random 1:1.5 in my file, what code i cant you?

Answer (score 3):

For quality results, you need ffmpeg compiled with librubberband. Or you can use the standalone [binary](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/) which works with WAV files.

Syntax for binary is

```
rubberband -t <timeratio> -p <pitchratio> <infile.wav> <outfile.wav>
```

e.g. `rubberband -t 1.5 -p 2.0 test.wav output.wav` extends duration by 50% and increases pitch by one tone (2 semitones).

Comment: There's a Windows compatible build compiled with it enabled available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpegwindowsbi/)